# Issue with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, raspberry-pi, java

I have installed netbeans in my PC (windows 7), wrote a javaFX application program and generated executable jar file

I finally need the executable jar file to be working on Raspberry pi linux and I want to use only **openjdk** since **oracle java for Rpi doesn't support AWT and Swing** and my application majorly includes that.

When i tried to execute the jar file using openjdk, i am getting an error - you need to install newer version of JRE to execute this file. I have also tried to execute the same file in ubuntu to verify if there is something wrong and its showing the same error

But, the jar file was executed properly through oracle java in ubuntu. I also tried using Oracle java on RPi, but it opened but didn't work properly.(expected, because it doesn't support AWT and Swing)

So, I think i have an issue opening the file using openjdk. Can somebody help me with this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the process of buying my Raspberry Pi but have already started looking at the development environment I will need. You may find what you are looking for in these very clear resources I found:

1. http://adf4beginners.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-get-java-embedded-suite-running.html
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/rel/8/rpi/html/getstart_rpi/toc.htm

As Ryanteck mentioned, you will probably have to be running Raspbian (item number 1, the tutorial, uses that OS).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi's recommended OS does not support Java at all. The main thing to try is to test it using the Debian Soft float image which should support Java on the Raspberry Pi fine. But it is still in development so may not work.